# MEAN stack: can't display data from a single Mongodb element by it's id

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, angular4-httpclient

using a service and api to connect to I was able to display the whole array from my mongodb collection in catalog.component.ts :
api.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router=express.Router();

const app=express();
const MongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const ObjectID=require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var path=require('path');
var db;

const connection=(closure) => {
    return MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', (err, client)=>{
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        db=client.db('angulardb');
        closure(db);

    });
};


const sendError =(err, res)=>{
    response.status=501;
    response.message=typeof err == 'object' ? err.message : err;
    res.status(501).json(response);
};

let response={
    status:200,
    data:[],
    message: null
};

router.post('/getProducts',(req, res) => {

  connection((db) => {
    db.collection('products')
      .find()
      .toArray()
      .catch((err)=>{
        sendError(err, res);
        response.message ={ success:"Se obtuvieron los registros correctamente", error:""};
        res.send({response});
      })
      .then((result)=>{

        response.data= result;
        res.send({response});
      });
  });
});

router.post('/getProduct',(req, res) => {
  connection((db) => {
    db.collection('products')
      .find({id:new ObjectID(req.query.id)})
      .toArray()
      .catch((err)=>{
        sendError(err, res);
        response.message ={ success:"Se obtuvieron los registros correctamente", error:""};
        res.send({response});
      })
      .then((result)=>{

        response.data= result;
        res.send({response});
      });
  });
});
module.exports=router;
```

service where I added the getProducts function for catalog and getProduct function for details

```
mongo2.service.ts:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable()
export class Mongo2Service {

  constructor( private _http: HttpClient) { }


  getProducts() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this._http.post('/api/getProducts', { headers })
      .catch( (error: any) => Observable.throw(error || 'server error'));
  }

  getProduct(id: number) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const params = {'id': id};
    return this._http.post('/api/getProduct', { headers, params})
      .catch( (error: any) => Observable.throw(error || 'server error'));
  }
}
```

Here I get the array from mongodb collection catalog.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Mongo2Service} from '../mongo2.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-catalog',
  templateUrl: './catalog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./catalog.component.css']
})
export class CatalogComponent implements OnInit {
products: any;
respuesta: any;


  constructor( private mongo2Service: Mongo2Service) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  this.getProducts();

  }

  getProducts() {

    this.mongo2Service.getProducts().subscribe(respuesta => {
      this.respuesta = respuesta;
      this.products = this.respuesta.response.data;
      console.log(this.respuesta);
    });
  }
}
```

And I get displayed the mongodb collecction
[collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wko8x.png)
in this list:
[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B3yk.png)

I add a router link to that list in catalog component with the selected element's id to another component called 'details' which has a 'getProduct' method in api and the service, but the view doesn't display the element's name or id:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Mongo2Service} from '../mongo2.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.css']
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  respuesta: any;
  products:any;

    constructor(private location: Location,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
   ,private mongo2Service: Mongo2Service) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.getProduct();
  }


  getProduct() {
    const id=+ this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('_id');
    console.log('entro funcion componente');

    this.mongo2Service.getProduct(id).subscribe(respuesta => {
      this.respuesta = respuesta;
      this.products = this.respuesta.response.data; 
      console.log(this.respuesta);
    });
  }

  goBack(): void{
  this.location.back();
  }
}
```

Comment: `.find({ id: new ObjectID(req.query.id) })` should be `.find({ _id: new ObjectID(req.query.id) })`. That's `_id` and not `id` for the primary key as an `ObjectId` Check your inputs and make sure you are posting valid query parameters which actually provide something that should match. If still unsure, then show a document you expect to match and what the sent parameters on the request actually are.

Comment: Are you able to get the id from `req.query.id`? Try `console.log(req.query.id)` >

Comment: yes, I can see the id on the route when I run the details component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it , I edited the getProduct method in api.js  by changing `req.query._id`  for `req.body.id` inside find.() as you can see:

```
router.post('/getProduct',(req, res) => {
  var find={ id: new ObjectID(req.body.id) };
  console.log(find);
  connection((db) => {
    db.collection('products')
      .find({_id:new ObjectID(req.body.id)})
      .toArray()
      .catch((err)=>{
        sendError(err, res);
        response.message ={ success:"Se obtuvieron los registros correctamente", error:""};
        res.send({response});
      })
      .then((result)=>{
        response.data= result;
        res.send({response});
      });
  });
});
```

I also deleted the '+' at the const id  and added another variable (product:any) to the method in details with the position [0] in data.

```
 getProduct() {

    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('_id');

    console.log(id);
    this.mongo2Service.getProduct(id).subscribe(respuesta => {
      this.respuesta = respuesta;
      this.product = this.respuesta.response.data[0];
      console.log(this.respuesta);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Good catch!! +1 vote for that
So you were doing wrong in two places. 1. In the find query [changing id to _id] (Like I explained in below answer) and 2. In the  getProduct() function.

Comment: Also, you should add length check to avoid errors for this.respuesta.response.data. eg. if (this.respuesta.response.data.length) { this.product = this.respuesta.response.data }

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB creates **_id** and not **id**, your match condition is wrong for getting the results.

I have updated the query and added the console log, check the console if you're getting expected result now.

```
    router.post('/getProduct',(req, res) => {
      connection((db) => {
        db.collection('products')
          .find({_id:new ObjectID(req.query.id)})
          .toArray()
          .catch((err)=>{
            sendError(err, res);
            response.message ={ success:"Se obtuvieron los registros correctamente", error:""};
            res.send({response});
          })
          .then((result)=>{

            console.log("Expected Results: ", result);

            response.data= result;
            res.send({response});
          });
      });
    });
```

This should get you details for the single product. Check how you are using the returned data here.

Comment: thank you, I changed id for _id where you told me but the console log shows an empty array just like this : "Expected results:" [ ]

Comment: Can you re-check if the ID you are getting is in the database for product collection >> _id field?

Comment: well, I have a _id in my database, but I couldn't get it in the response

Comment: Wasn't this any help to you? I mean the _id and id thing, you used in  db.collection('products')
          .find({_id:new ObjectID(req.query.id)}) ??